# DB2 SQL nested queries

Tags: sql, db2

I need to list the first name and last name of the youngest patient that is prescribed penicillin, using nested queries. Here is what I have

```
SELECT P.FIRST_NAME, P.LAST_NAME, MIN(P.AGE) AS AGE
FROM PATIENT AS P
WHERE P.PATIENT_NO IN(
    SELECT PRE.PATIENT_NO
    FROM PRESCRIPTION AS PRE
    WHERE MEDICATION_CODE IN (
            SELECT M.MEDICATION_CODE
            FROM MEDICATION AS M
            WHERE MEDICATION_DESC = 'Penicillin'))
GROUP BY P.FIRST_NAME, P.LAST_NAME
HAVING MIN(P.AGE);
```

The results come back with the two people that are prescribed penicillin, not just the youngest.

Comment: I suspect you could do it with a join,post your tables schemas

Comment: your query is finding the minimum age for each person who has ever been prescribed penicillin. i'm assuming that each patient only has one age ;)

Comment: I don't think your `HAVING` is accomplishing what you want.... but aside, I'm surprised you're not getting an error message for that `HAVING MIN(P.AGE);`, because it's intended to give a boolean result (logical phrase with a true/false result).  For example, `HAVING MIN(P.AGE) < 20` would be complete syntax for a `HAVING`.

Comment: Nested querries is specified.  Can't use join

Comment: What if it's a tie?  If you need all records when there is a tie, use the rank function described here  http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.apsg%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_rankrows.htm

Comment: ...I'm a little afraid to ask, but _why_ are joins not allowed?  Depending on the case, you may get a better-performing query.  Note that storing age in a DB is not terribly useful - it needs to be updated every year (on the birthday, which means either you're storing that info already, or your expecting the patient to remind you, which isn't going to happen).  Along with this, hopefully the `Prescription` table has a list of date issued, which would allow you to figure out the age of the patient at the time it was issued.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you have to use nested queries?

In any case, the `having` clause is not doing what you want.  You can get what you want by doing this:

```
SELECT P.FIRST_NAME, P.LAST_NAME, MAX(P.AGE) as AGE
FROM PATIENT AS P
WHERE P.PATIENT_NO IN (
    SELECT PRE.PATIENT_NO
    FROM PRESCRIPTION AS PRE
    WHERE MEDICATION_CODE IN (
            SELECT M.MEDICATION_CODE
            FROM MEDICATION AS M
            WHERE MEDICATION_DESC = 'Penicillin'
                             )
   )
GROUP BY P.FIRST_NAME, P.LAST_NAME
ORDER BY MAX(P.AGE)
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

**EDIT:**

Actually, I agree with FloChanz, and the `group by` is probably not necessary (unless you need to remove duplicates):

```
SELECT P.FIRST_NAME, P.LAST_NAME, P.AGE
FROM PATIENT AS P
WHERE P.PATIENT_NO IN (
    SELECT PRE.PATIENT_NO
    FROM PRESCRIPTION AS PRE
    WHERE MEDICATION_CODE IN (
            SELECT M.MEDICATION_CODE
            FROM MEDICATION AS M
            WHERE MEDICATION_DESC = 'Penicillin'
                             )
   )
ORDER BY P.AGE
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: Something is missing from last line and is throwing an error.

Comment: You should add P.AGE in the select statement and the GROUP BY in order to be able to ORDER BY on this column. But I don't think the group by clause is useful in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that some inner join might be better like this :

```
SELECT P.FIRST_NAME, P.LAST_NAME, P.AGE
FROM MEDICATION AS M 
INNER JOIN PRESCRIPTION AS PRE on PRE.MEDICATION_CODE = M.MEDICATION_CODE
INNER JOIN PATIENT AS P on P.PATIENT_NO = PRE.PATIENT_NO
WHERE M.MEDICATION_DESC = 'Penicillin'
ORDER BY P.AGE 
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: No nested queries needed.  Good job.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  Thanks for all the suggestions

```
SELECT P.FIRST_NAME, P.LAST_NAME
 FROM PATIENT AS P
WHERE P.AGE IN (
 SELECT MIN(P.AGE)
 FROM PATIENT AS P
 WHERE  P.PATIENT_NO IN(
SELECT PRE.PATIENT_NO
FROM PRESCRIPTION AS PRE
WHERE MEDICATION_CODE IN (
        SELECT M.MEDICATION_CODE
        FROM MEDICATION AS M
        WHERE MEDICATION_DESC = 'Penicillin')));
```